# Can I remove Old Database Instance after Performing Upgrade?

Tags: sql-server

My server has a MS SQL server 2000 database engine. Recently I installed another database engine (MS SQL server 2005). I've also "upgraded" all of the database instance.

The way I did this is to:

1. Create a backup of database instance from MS SQL server 2000
2. Import that instance into the 2005.

So now my application would be using the 2005 instance instead of the 2000. My question is, given that the old database instance is very big (about 20GB), can I delete it to free up the disk space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I'd set all the services to "disabled" to shut down the SQL Server 2000 engine.

Any user MDFs and LDFs files for that instance can be deleted if you are *happy* you won't rollback. Files or backups from the SQL Server 2005 instance *can not* be restored back.

I'd tend to make one last backup of all databases and store them safely too

Answer (score 0):

You've installed a new instance of SQL server, you haven't upgraded the instance. You've moved the databases from the SQL 2000 instance to the SQL 2005 instance. There's no such thing as a database instance.

If you're satisfied with the operation of the database in the new SQL 2005 instance then there's no need to keep it in the SQL 2000 instance. Get a final backup of the database from the SQL 2000 instance, delete the database, and uninstall the SQL 2000 instance.